# Ignore validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I have a viewmodel with two other models in it. Both have fields that are required(done with entity framework).

```
    public class featureModel
    {

        public FEATURE FEATURE { get; set; }


        public REQUIREMENTS REQUIREMENTS { get; set; }
    }
```

On my page I have a dropdownlist, which is populated like this

```
ViewBag.FEATURE_ID = new SelectList(db.FEATURE, "FEATURE_ID", "Name_");
```

on view

```
@Html.DropDownList("FEATURE_ID", "ADD FEATURE")
```

Which will be a dropdownlist of all the features found, and on the top a ADD FEATURE option(when this is selected, i have some js to show the fields the user should input). IF this option is selected, then the user would need to input certain fields, if not they should not(and the fields are hidden). When my page validates, it requires that this needs to be populated, which makes sense in terms of validation.

Is there a way that I can set a condition to ignore this validation if the dropdownlist is on a certain option?

Comment: You should adhere to [design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke(v=vs.71).aspx) for which ever language you are developing in. In particular, use Pacal casing for class names in C# - see [Capitalization Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: will do, typically i just used the convention that anything I created would be in the form on xxxxYYYY, and all caps are what the entity framework generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implement `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.IValidatableObject` on your ViewModel and perform validation there:

```
public class featureModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public FEATURE FEATURE { get; set; }
    public REQUIREMENTS REQUIREMENTS { get; set; }
    public bool FeaturesRequired { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (featuresRequired)
        {
            // do your feature check here
            if (FEATURE == null)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("You must enter a feature.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have a hidden field on your view that provides a value for `FeaturesRequired` (you could do this with javascript so `onchange` of your drop down) which can then be checked on model validation.

**IValidatable with unobtrusive ajax (client-side validation)**

Have a look at [this resource](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/07/ivalidatableobject-client-side.html) for validating `IValidatableObject` on client-side.

Comment: Will this override the entity-framework generated validation?

Comment: @user1714509 yes, this code will be executed when entity framework validates the model.

Comment: hey, i tried this method, but it still says the fields are required.

Comment: i placed a breakpoint in my code and it doesn't even reach the if(featuresRequired) point

Comment: also another side note, this validation needs to be ignored before the form gets POST, the form still requires that the fields be required before sending

Comment: @user1714509 are you talking about validating with unobtrusive ajax?

Comment: yes, well not validating with unobtrusive ajax if fields are hidden

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to ignore the jquery validation for hidden fields. You can try this.

```
  var validator = $("#formId").data('validator');
  validator.settings.ignore = ":hidden";
```

At the server-side clear the errors from the `ModelState` as said by @Forty-Two

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to ModelState errors in your controller when you say "when my page validates", then you can use

```
ModelState.Clear()
```

to clear all errors or

```
ModelState.Remove(string key)
```

to clear specific errors.  You can check the value of the dropdown list and then decide which model errors (if any) to remove.

EDIT

ignore jquery validation

```
$("#formId").validate({  //Your form id 
   ignore: "#ignoreFieldId"  //you can use any selector you want here: class, etc
})
```

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but, i think this works after the form has been posted. I was definitely unclear, but when i say when my page validates, i mean before the page gets sent.

Comment: Your answer then lies in bypassing the client side validation. You'll need to either change the validation rules as Terric points out below, or look into the jQuery .ignore function to disable the unobtrusive validation for certain fields.

Comment: its a problem with the unobtrusive,  i need to ignore hidden fields somehow

Comment: @user1714509 Edited answer with jquery.ignore()

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">    $("#feature").validate({
        ignore: "FEATURE_NAME_"
    });
</script> still won't work

Comment: @user1714509 you need to use a proper selector.  Look at the rendered html and decide how to do it.  If the (hidden?) field that holds FEATURE_NAME_ has an id="FEATURE_NAME_" then the code would be  ignore: "#FEATURE_NAME_".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18488/discussion-between-user1714509-and-forty-two)